# attribute directive syntax with and without square bracket []

Tags: angular

The attribute directives are supposed to use selectors with `selector:'[myDirective]'` syntax and then used in templates like `<p myDirective ></p>'`. I also see that ngClass is an attribute directive and usage is like `[ngClass]="'class1 class2'"`. I want to know when is square bracket used and when it is not. Is it related to some relation between directive selector and property binding with the same name ?

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets are used when an expression need to be evaluated. **ngClass** can be used without brackets. Below code will treat class1 and class2 as normal string.

```
ngClass="class1 class2"
```

Comment: why is there no need of single quotes here ?

Comment: As ngClass don't have square brackets angular will treat class1 class2 as normal string. Ang if there was bracket it will treat them as variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what kind of entity your are working with. 
In selectors you can, if you working on a component either write:

```
selector:'[myComponent]'  => <div myComponent></div>
```

or

```
selector:'myComponent'   => <myComponent></myComponent>
```

When it comes attribute binding, you could write

```
<div [title]="theTitleProperty"></div>
```

which will bind the html title attribute to the value of the components property theTitleProperty. (alt div title="{{theTitleProperty}}")
while

```
<div title="theTitleProperty"></div>
```

will give the title the value 'theTitleProperty''

an alternative to ngClass could be

```
<div [class]="theClassProperty"></div>
```

And then its the @Inputs to a component.
Any component might have an @Input you can use it with both bracket or not
If you have a component with @Input() aText:string;
you could use it like this:

```
<my-component [aText]="myTextProperty"></div>
```

And it would send the control property myTextProperty to the components @Input
But if you write like this

```
<my-component aText="myTextProperty"></div>
```

It would send myTextProperty into the component.

Hope it helps a little